# How can I show Interstitial ads in my flutter app after some fix time interval?

Tags: flutter, dart, ads, interstitial

I want to add Interstitial ads in my Flutter  app  that should be shown after some fix time . For eg:- I want  Interstitial ads must be shown automatically after every 2 minutes . So , How can I add this functionality to my flutter app.And if possible then provide some example code to explain this functionality . Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like below,

```
Timer? timer;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 120), (Timer t) => ShowAds());
}

@override
void dispose() {
  timer?.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}
```